# What is the difference between geo DNS policy and local subnet prioritization (netmask ordering)?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, geodns, dns-policies

Starting with Windows Server 2016, MS DNS supports [DNS Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/dns-policies-overview) with "Geo-Location Based Traffic Management". But with older Windows Server versions I could configure [local subnet prioritization (aka netmask ordering)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961422.aspx) to implement a similar functionality (make clients in different subnets contact a resource in the same subnet using the same server name).

So my question is how geo DNS policies that were added in Windows Server 2016 are different from local subnet prioritization?

Comment: Traditionally "geo-based" means that some country is computed out of the client IP address (or ECS information) or smaller location area when possible/desired, and the response then depends on that. So that for example in case of a worldwide CDN, the customer gets the endpoint "closer" to its location. Where "subnet prioritization" just takes into account the IP address itself and its network as needed, without any other factor.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you, Patrick! I think that I understand the difference now.